# Error response from daemon: pull access denied for hospitalproject

Tags: spring, docker

When i i write docker compose up to terminal it gives an error like **server Error

Error response from daemon: pull access denied for hospitalproject, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied**

application.properties :

```
server.port=8080
#CodeFirst, DbFirst
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
# DataBase Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
spring.datasource.username=springstudent
spring.datasource.password=springstudent
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

Dockerfile :

```
FROM openjdk:20-alpine
WORKDIR /app
ADD target/hospitalproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar hospitalproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "hospitalproject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar"]
```

docker-compose.yml :

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    image: hospitalproject
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hospital?useUnicode=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone&jdbcCompliantTruncation=false
    networks:
      - springmysql-net
    depends_on:
      - localhost

  localhost:
    image: mysql:5.7
    networks:
      - springmysql-net
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=springstsudent
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=hospital
      - MYSQL_USER=springstudent
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=springstudent

networks:
  springmysql-net:
```

If you need any extra information to solve this problem i can edit question . Could you help me ? Thanks

Comment: It looks the docker is trying to pull the image `hospitalproject` from remote registry, because it is not exists in your local machine. Did you build the image with `Dockerfile`? Could you please confirm the image name is `hospitalproject`. Also try with [Compose file build](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#illustrative-example)